# Message Boxes in ASP.NET (MVC) Web Application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

In a windows form application, I would typically use the code `MessageBox.Show("error!")` to notify a user of an error for data validation, and I am aware that you can't do this in an asp.net application. After doing some basic research on the problem, I have come to the conclusion that a JQuery dialog box is probably the closest thing to a message box. What are some other alternatives to solve this problem, and is the JQuery dialog box the best way to handle this kind of problem? I am new to software development, mvc and JQuery, I just want to know the best programming practice to handle this problem.

Currently, this is the code I have in my controller:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateSearchBegin) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateSearchEnd))
{
    //string message = "Both date fields are required";              
}
else
{
   var dtFrom = DateTime.Parse(dateSearchBegin);
   var dtTo = DateTime.Parse(dateSearchEnd);
   return View(db.PurchaseOrders.Where(x => x.Date >= dtFrom && x.Date <= dtTo).OrderBy(i => i.Date).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 15));
}
```

I want to put the `string message` in the validation, how should I combat this problem?

Comment: You should look into ViewModels and Data Annotations

Comment: Where can I find out more info. about these subjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ModelState` for add custom error message

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateSearchBegin) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateSearchEnd))
 {
   ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Both date fields are required");
 }
```

End show in view:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is a great way to add data validation in asp.net!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to add validation to a model object, look into [Model Validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model) in [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc).

---

If you're looking for a way to notify the user of some message from the controller, check out [`ControllerBase.TempData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata(v=vs.118).aspx). It handles this precise scenario very well.

As a side note, I created a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BootstrapNotifications/), based on [Bootstrap Notifications](https://github.com/uacaps/BootstrapNotifications), that wraps this functionality up nicely in [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), and enables you to easily notify users from the controller using:

```
this.AddNotification("You have errors because you did it wrong!", NotificationType.ERROR);
```

from any Controller.

Comment: I will have to check out your NuGet Package... Is there a tutorial somewhere that shows how to implement your package into code?

Comment: there is a [downloadable demo project](https://github.com/uacaps/BootstrapNotifications/tree/master/src/BootstrapNotifications) and the [readme](https://github.com/uacaps/BootstrapNotifications/blob/master/README.md) explains how to install and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to make the Post to the Server , then return JsonResult from your Action. You can send back text/numbers to the client which you check to detect if your condition was not met on the server-side then display a javascript alert on the client browser.

Comment: What is Ajax? Is that  a package in the NuGet Manager?

Comment: Ajax is a technology that allows you to post data to the server asynchronously i.e without reloading of the whole page. Check for more information here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/